# Omission of verbs in 'the more... the more...' construction

Tags: verbs, subject-verb-agreement, comparative-constructions, comparative

Recently I found the following phrase in an English guide book:

> In all regions except Southeast Asia it can be seen that the higher
> the consumption of cigarettes, the higher the tobacco-related
> mortality rate.

My question is: shouldn't I put a verb in the end of each clause? This would be:

*In all regions except Southeast Asia it can be seen that the higher the consumption of
cigarettes **is**, the higher the tobacco-related mortality rate **is**.*

Another example from the same book:

> The more accurate your use of modifiers the better your writing will
> be.

I strongly want to put 'is' after the word 'modifiers,' what's the reason it is omitted? Is there any rule for this?

In case you wonder: it is a volume published by Academic English Press, so I assume this omission isn't a mistake. I just want to know why they omit the verb there, since I haven't come across such examples before.

Comment: The noun is [**omission**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/omission), not *omitment*.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not necessary to include verbs. This is an established usage in English - compare the idiom [the more the merrier](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/more-the-merrier), meaning 'the more people are present, the more successful the event will be'.

Comment: True, but what confuses me is that they have the subject, whereas in constructions like 'the more, the merrier, neither a subject nor a verb are present.

Comment: You just have to accept that "The more X the more Y", "The higher the X, the higher the Y" are idiomatic English.

Comment: Sure, it is just that I don't understand when I can normally omit verbs, cos many phrases like that contain them. Is it just a matter of choice then?

Comment: No, it isn't - your amended sentence with the repeated **is** is not idiomatic.  You need to include verbs if the two phrases being compared use different verbs, for example _The higher up the mountain they climbed, the colder the weather became._

Comment: But it doesn't work with the following sentence (from the same source): 'The more accurate your use of modifiers the better your writing will be.' It seems that only is/are tend to be omitted.